# settimeout to blink of button

Tags: jquery

In jquery I have a button with a fading effect:

```
function blinky() {
    $('#ButtonContent_btnSubmit').delay(100).fadeTo(100, 0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100, 1, blinky);    
}
```

This causes a nice blinking effect, but I only want the blinking effect to last for say 10 seconds.

I want it to only blink for say 10 seconds...Could I apply `setTimeout()` to this?  I tried to apply setTimeout like so:

```
function blinky() {
    setTimeout($('#ButtonContent_btnSubmit').delay(100).fadeTo(100, 0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100, 1, blinky), 100);  
}
```

But this does not seem to work.

## Edit

Im a jquery noob so Im trying to get this to work...
Lets say here is my document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if ($('#StatusContent_ddlStatus').val() == "Not Submitted" && $("#LineItemContent_gvLineItems tr").length > 0) {
              blink();
        }
});

var count = 0;

function blink() {
    if (++count < 10)
        $('#ButtonContent_btnSubmit').delay(100).fadeTo(100, 0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100, 1, blink);
}​
```

In developer tools (chrome) it throws some sort of exception...

### Edit 2

If I put it all in document ready:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     if ($('#StatusContent_ddlStatus').val() == "Not Submitted" && $("#LineItemContent_gvLineItems tr").length > 0) {
                  blink();
            }

 var count = 0;

    function blink() {
        if (++count < 10)
            $('#ButtonContent_btnSubmit').delay(100).fadeTo(100, 0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100, 1, blink);
    }​

    });
```

Then in developer tools it says Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token illegal.

## Edit 3

I tried to place it at the top before calling it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 0; 
        var f = 0;

         function blink() { 
            if (++count < 10) 
                $('#ButtonContent_btnSubmit').delay(100).fadeTo(100, 0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100, 1,        blink); 
            }

          if ($('#StatusContent_ddlStatus').val() == "Not Submitted" && $("#LineItemContent_gvLineItems tr").length > 0) {
            blink();
        }
});
```

Same issue...

Comment: what does `blink()` (your callback) do ? does it re-loop the same function ?

Comment: `setTimeout` will delay execution of the callback until the time has passed. The code as you wrote it amounts to "wait 100ms, then call this jQuery."

Comment: see my answer, tested and works, or check answer of the guy who copied me..

Comment: use the second edit and put the `var count = 0;` right in the beginning of the ready event. above everything else in there.

Comment: @gdoron - you mean right after `$(document).ready(function() {` I added `var count=0;` and still same issue

Comment: You use the `blink` function before it was declared. please give me a full fiddle and I try to help you.

Comment: gdoron - see edit 3.  I declare blink...then I have an if statement, is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: @oJM86o. you forgot the `@` sign in your comment so I wasn't notified by your comment... anyway please paste **all** of your code to http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: There was a unicode character copied from here onto my page and I couldnt see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a **lot simpler**, just save the number of calls to the `blink` function:

```
var count = 0;

function blinky() {
    if (++count < 10)
        $('#ButtonContent_btnSubmit').delay(100).fadeTo(100, 0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100, 1, blinky);
}​
```

Or with time limitation:

```
var startDate = new Date().getTime();
function blinky() {
    if (new Date().getTime() - startDate < 10000)
        $('#ButtonContent_btnSubmit').delay(100).fadeTo(100, 0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100, 1, blinky);
}​
```

Comment: @oJM86o. it was because you had a typo in the question and I copied it, try again

Comment: gdoron Im a jquery newbie, can I declare count outside of document.ready?  When I run your code I get a uncaught syntaxerror exception in google chromes developer tools

Comment: @gdoron - I think the iteration over the count variable in the first example is the better and less overhead option. Agree? using time for this solution somehow seems 'klunky', like an old diesel engine that runs, but with some fumes leaking here and there ;) I know they both work well, but option one feels.. right!

Comment: gdoron can we chat for a few seconds I just have a question and it is hard to explain over comments?

Comment: @OneStuckPixel. you're right, it's plan B... :). But unless it's a real time application for jets, the overhead is very unlikely to be notices by anyone (except Chuck Norris...).

Comment: @oJM86o. for some reason the chat doesn't work for me. just paste all of your code in a jsFiddle. cool?

Comment: gordon - do i define the function outside of document ready?  like this: `$(document).ready(function () { //all my code }); var count = 0; 
        function blink() { 
        if (++count < 10) 
            $('#ButtonContent_btnSubmit').delay(100).fadeTo(100, 0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100, 1, blink); 
        }` it then doesnt work...does it not see the variable count?  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @oJM86o. Try putting **all the code inside** the ready event. jsFiddle can be the best way for me to show you how to do it right, If I can...

Comment: @gdoron - I tried putting it all inside document ready see edit 2 above in my question

Answer (score 0):

Try marking the time and checking against it like:

```
var markTime = new Date().getTime();

function blinky() {
  $('#ButtonContent_btnSubmit').delay(100).fadeTo(100, 0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100, 1, function() {
    if(new Date().getTime() < (markTime + 10000)) blinky();
  });    
}

blinky();
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work-->

```
var stopT=false;
```

var timerHdl=null;
$(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function(){stopT=true;}, 10000);
    blink();

});
function blink(){
    if(stopT===true) {clearTimeout(timerHdl); return;}   timerHdl = setTimeout(function(){$('#ButtonContent_btnSubmit').delay(100).fadeTo(100, 0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100, 1, blink)}, 100);
}

​

Comment: @OneStuckPixel. did that, and it won't work, it will blink for ever...!